# Azure-CLI/Powershell Password requirments

Tags: regex, azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-cli2

So i am trying to make a variable match the password requirements for making a virtual machine in azure CLI

to do this it must have 3 of the following !uppercase, 1 lowercase 1 special character or a number

This is the main code i am trying to change

```
$AdminPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Please insert a Admin Password (Password must have 3 of the following: 1 lower case character, 1 upper case character, 1 number and 1 special character)"
```

This is the code i changed but isn't working correctly

```
do 
    {
        $AdminPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Please insert a Admin Password (Password must have the 3 of the following: 1 lower case character, 1 upper case character, 1 number and 1 special character)"
    }
    until($AdminPassword -Like "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][!@$#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};'':"\\|,.<>\/? ][!@$#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};'':"\\|,.<>\/? ][!@$#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};'':"\\|,.<>\/? ]")
    Write Match
```

with the write match line i know when it succeeds

the real trouble i have here is that i want all 4 of the requirements 3 times so 3 uppercase's 3 lowercase's etc 
and i also want to have the special characters 
but the # comments all the code that follows out [image: like this]

thanks in advance for reading this and posting your anwser!!!

Comment: added the regex tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can be done with just one regex..
As an alternative, below a small helper function to do the tests.

```
function Test-AdminPassword {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Password,

        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [int]$Requirements = 5
    )
    $result = 0

    # test length between 12 and 24
    if ($Password.Length -in 12..24) {
        $result++
    }
    # test uppercase
    if (($Password -creplace '[^A-Z]', '').Length -ge 3) {
        $result++
    }
    # test lowercase
    if (($Password -creplace '[^a-z]', '').Length -ge 3) {
        $result++
    }
    # test digits
    if (($Password -replace '[^0-9]', '').Length -ge 3) {
        $result++
    }
    # test special characters
    if (($Password -creplace '[^!@$#%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};'':"\\|,.<>\/? ]', '').Length -ge 3) {
        $result++
    }

    # return $true if the password complies with at least $requirements
    return ($result -ge $Requirements)
}

do {
    $AdminPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Please insert an Admin Password (must have the 3 lower case characters, 3 upper case characters, 3 digits and 3 special characters)"
} until (Test-AdminPassword $AdminPassword)
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser Theo! the only thing i forgot to mention in the question is that it needs to have a minimum of 12 characters and a maximum of 24. do you perhaps also know how to get a maximum?

Comment: @Brynn I have updated the answer to test the password length between 12 and 24 (inclusive) too. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you very much Theo! now i wish i could upvote twice!
i appreciate the time and effort you put into this, i hope you will have a great day today!

Comment: Short update: it doesn't work with the maximum length because then the script just goes to the next step :( ill try to find a solution for this @Theo

Comment: @Brynn. I forgot to change the number of requirements. It should now be `[int]$Requirements = 5` because we have added a new test. Sorry for that..

Comment: Ah that makes sense! thank you for the fast reply! and its no problem to make a mistake isn't it @Theo? (at least i don't have a problem with mistakes because you learn from those)

Comment: is there perhaps a way to use this method to except for example special characters?
i am also using this method for admin username  and i would like to exclude every option that is other than lower cases.
i already checked google one of the sites i visted is [link](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html) but i couldnt find a exclude option yet @Theo

Comment: Well, it is easy to adapt, however, it would be better if you post a new question for that instead of extending this one. That way you can define your exact requirements like min/max length, special characters or not, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Theo i made a new question that continues on this question
Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857058/azure-cli-powershell-how-to-exclude-requirements) to it

Comment: Thank you again Theo i just marked it as an anwser!

Answer (score 1):

For the special characters,the regular expression should be the one in the code below.

You need to use single quote for your regular expression:

```
do
{
$s=Read-Host -Prompt "please enter a password"
}
until($s -like '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][!@$#$%^&*()_+\-\=`[`]{};'':`"\\|,.<>\/? ][!@$#$%^&*()_+\-\=`[`]{};'':`"\\|,.<>\/? ][!@$#$%^&*()_+\-\=`[`]{};'':`"\\|,.<>\/? ]')

write-host "complete entering password"
```

Test result as below:
[image]

Comment: But this does not allow for `AaBbCc1!2@3#` or passwords that have more than the minimal required characters

Comment: Hey Ivan Thanks for the anwser! unfortunatly i forgot to mention this is the minimum of characters it needs and that i can have more than 12 characters anyways here is a upvote because your anwser is also correct! again thank you very much for the anwser!!!