# Azure CLI\Powershell How to exclude requirements

Tags: regex, azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-cli2

So as a continuation of my last question [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837260/azure-cli-powershell-password-requirments/52838881?noredirect=1#comment92626231_52838881).
i got this code as a anwser but now i wold like how i could exclude some requirements

```
function Test-AdminPassword {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Password,

    [Parameter(Position = 1)]
    [int]$Requirements = 5
)
$result = 0

# test length between 12 and 24
if ($Password.Length -in 12..24) {
    $result++
}
# test uppercase
if (($Password -creplace '[^A-Z]', '').Length -ge 3) {
    $result++
}
# test lowercase
if (($Password -creplace '[^a-z]', '').Length -ge 3) {
    $result++
}
# test digits
if (($Password -replace '[^0-9]', '').Length -ge 3) {
    $result++
}
# test special characters
if (($Password -creplace '[^!@$#%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};'':"\\|,.<>\/? ]', '').Length -ge 3) {
    $result++
}

# return $true if the password complies with at least $requirements
return ($result -ge $Requirements)
}
```

the question i have now is how can i edit this so i can exclude special characters because in a Admin Username you can use only lowercase characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete re-write of my earlier function.
This one uses a lot more parameters for you to play with, but then it can be used for testing both an admin username and also to test an inputted password.

```
function Test-AdminInput {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = "ByCase")]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$NameOrPassword,

        # Instead of these default numbers, you can set them all to 0
        # if you like. That way, omitting them from the call will skip the test.
        [int]$MinLength = 12,
        [int]$MaxLength = 24,
        [int]$MinDigits = 3,
        [int]$MinSpecial = 3,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "ByCase")]
        [int]$MinUpperCase = 3,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "ByCase")]
        [int]$MinLowerCase = 3,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "ByCaseRestrict")]
        [ValidateSet ("AllUpperCase","AllLowerCase","Any")]
        [string]$RestrictCase = "Any"
    )
    # test $MinLength
    if ($MinLength -gt 0 -and $NameOrPassword.Length -lt $MinLength) {
        Write-Warning "You need at least $MinLength characters"
        return $false
    }

    # test $MaxLength
    if ($MaxLength -gt 0 -and $NameOrPassword.Length -gt $MaxLength) {
        Write-Warning "You cannot use more than $MaxLength characters"
        return $false
    }

    # test Restricted casing
    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "ByCaseRestrict") {
        switch ($RestrictCase) {
            "AllUpperCase" { if ($NameOrPassword.ToUpperInvariant() -cne $NameOrPassword)  { 
                             Write-Warning "You must use upper-case characters only"; return $false } }
            "AllLowerCase" { if ($NameOrPassword.ToLowerInvariant() -cne $NameOrPassword)  { 
                             Write-Warning "You must use lower-case characters only"; return $false } }
        }
    }
    else {
        # test minimum uppercase
        if ($MinUpperCase -gt 0) {
            if (($NameOrPassword -creplace '[^A-Z]', '').Length -lt $MinUpperCase) { 
                Write-Warning "You must use at least $MinUpperCase upper-case characters" 
                return $false
            }
        }
        # test minimum lowercase
        if ($MinLowerCase -gt 0) {
            if (($NameOrPassword -creplace '[^a-z]', '').Length -lt $MinLowerCase) { 
                Write-Warning "You must use at least $MinLowerCase lower-case characters" 
                return $false
            }
        }
    }

    # test digits
    if ($MinDigits -gt 0) {
        if (($NameOrPassword -replace '[^0-9]', '').Length -lt $MinDigits) {
            Write-Warning "You must use at least $MinDigits digits (0-9)" 
            return $false
        }
    }
    # test special characters
    if ($MinSpecial -gt 0) {
        if (($NameOrPassword -creplace '[^!@$#%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};'':"\\|,.<>\/? ]', '').Length -lt $MinSpecial) {
            Write-Warning "You must use at least $MinSpecial special characters (!@$#%^&*()_+-=[]{};'`":\|,.<>/? )" 
            return $false
        }
    }

    # If you get here, all tests succeeded
    return $true
}
```

For testing Passwords use it like this:

```
do {
    $input = Read-Host -Prompt "Please insert an Admin Password (must have the 3 lower case characters, 3 upper case characters, 3 digits and 3 special characters)"
    $result = Test-AdminInput $input -MinLength 12 -MaxLength 24 -MinUpperCase 3 -MinLowerCase 3 -MinDigits 3 -MinSpecial 3
} until ($result)
```

For testing User names use it like this:

```
do {
    $input = Read-Host -Prompt "Please insert an Admin User name (must have only lower case characters, 3 digits)"
    $result = Test-AdminInput $input -MinLength 12 -MaxLength 24 -MinDigits 3 -RestrictCase AllLowerCase
} until ($result)
```

Comment: thanks for the anwser! i tried expanding the function so it can also be used for the storage account the only thing i have there is it can only have lowercase characters and numbers and thusfar it just continues when you enter anything other then that do you perhas know something to fix it or should i make a new qeustion?

Comment: @Brynn For that you want a simpler solution. If your only restrictions are `Lowercase and or Digits` you could do something like this: `do { $input = Read-Host -Prompt "Please insert an User name (must have only lower case characters and/or digits)" } until ($input -cmatch '\A(?:[a-z0-9]+)\Z')`

Comment: Hi @Theo is there perhaps also a way to adda length between the 3 and 24 characters? i already tried to add `.Length -ge 3`

Comment: Sure. Just add `-and $input.Length -in 3..24` after the match test between the brackets.